# if statement to check file size AND file extension

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've got a basic if statement to check a file input's `size` and `extension`. Both my statements work separately, but I can't get both of them to work together.

To validate the extension:

```
//check file extension

let filename = imgInput.value
let last_dot = filename.lastIndexOf('.')
let ext = filename.slice(last_dot + 1)


if(ext !== 'jpg' || ext !== 'png' ){
    imgClient.innerHTML = 'Please select 1 JPG or PNG file less than 5mb'
    e.preventDefault()
} else {
    imgClient.innerHTML = ''
}
```

To validate the size:

```
// validate file size

if(imgInput.files[0]){
    let imgSize = imgInput.files[0].size
    if(imgSize > 5087408 ){
        imgClient.innerHTML = 'Your file is too big, please select an image under 5mb'
        e.preventDefault()
    } else {
        imgClient.innerHTML = ''
    }
}
```

One works when I comment the other out, but when I try both of them, only the first one executes.

I'm sure this might be a simple fix, I'm just stuck trying to figure it out... thanks for looking!

Comment: Unrelated, but you'll want to double-check your extension check logic.

Comment: Setting imgClient.innerHTML will replace previously set html of imgClient element. So it will never display both messages. Simple but dirty fix is on the second message make it as imgClient.innerHTML = imgClient.innerHTML  + " Your error message" (Need further more formatting). As for the extension check, it should be && not || since you want to display the error when both conditions eval to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues.

1. It should be && not || on the if statement since you want to check for if uploaded file is not a png or a jpg
2. Setting imgClient.innerHTML will replace previously set html of imgClient element. So it will never display both messages.

Didn't run following but it should work with what you have

```
function isAllowedExtension(imgInput) {
    let filename = imgInput.value
    let last_dot = filename.lastIndexOf('.')
    let ext = filename.slice(last_dot + 1)

    if (ext !== 'jpg' && ext !== 'png') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function isFileSizeRequirementMet(imgInput) {
    if (imgInput.files[0]) {
        let imgSize = imgInput.files[0].size
        if (imgSize > 5087408) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var extensionNotAllowed = !isAllowedExtension(imgInput);
var sizeRequirementNotMet = !isFileSizeRequirementMet(imgInput);
var fileTooLargeMessage = 'Your file is too big, please select an image under 5mb.';
var fileExtensionNotAllowedMessage = 'Please select 1 JPG or PNG file less than 5mb.';

if(extensionNotAllowed && sizeRequirementNotMet) {
    return `${fileTooLargeMessage} ${fileExtensionNotAllowedMessage}`;
}else if(extensionNotAllowed) {
    return `${fileExtensionNotAllowedMessage}`;
}else if(sizeRequirementNotMet) {
    return `${fileTooLargeMessage}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@printfmyname he said right
imgClient.innerHTML = '' or others will let the imgInput.files empty
so it will not check second successful
so you can use the code by:

```
let filename = imgInput.value
let last_dot = filename.lastIndexOf('.')
let ext = filename.slice(last_dot + 1)


if(ext !== 'jpg' || ext !== 'png' ){
    imgClient.innerHTML = 'Please select 1 JPG or PNG file less than 5mb'
    e.preventDefault()
} else {
    if(imgInput.files[0]){
        let imgSize = imgInput.files[0].size
        if(imgSize > 5087408 ){
            imgClient.innerHTML = 'Your file is too big, please select an image under 5mb'
            e.preventDefault()
        } else {
            imgClient.innerHTML = ''
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//try

```
e.preventDefault();
let filename = imgInput.value
let ext = filename.split('.').pop(); 
imgClient.innerHTML = '';

if(ext !== 'jpg' || ext !== 'png' ){

    imgClient.innerHTML += 'Please select ......';
    let imgSize = imgInput.files[0].size;
    if(imgSize > 5087408 )
    imgClient.innerHTML += ' <br> Your file is too big....'    
}
```